# Setting up of ldapConfiguration Enviromental Properties in Jenkins using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to configure Environment properties 
com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout and com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout using groovy script on jenkins .

snippet :
i tried using

```
ldap  =  [
                    new LDAPSecurityRealm.EnvironmentProperty('com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout', '5000'),
                    new LDAPSecurityRealm.EnvironmentProperty('com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout','6000'),
] as LDAPSecurityRealm.EnvironmentProperty[]

SecurityRealm ldap_ex = new LDAPSecurityRealm(server,rootDN,userSearchBase,userSearch,groupSearchBase,managerDN,managerPassword,inhibitInferRootDN,disableMailAddressResolver,enable_cache,ldap)
Jenkins.instance.setSecurityRealm(ldap_ex)
Jenkins.instance.save()
```

But i always get

```
[hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$EnvironmentProperty@5baed704, hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$EnvironmentProperty@71c1d902]
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.Boolean, hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$CacheConfiguration, [Lhudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$EnvironmentProperty;)
```

i see [Lhudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$EnvironmentProperty;)  is the list but i need an array as per the constructor documentation :

(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$CacheConfiguration,**hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$EnvironmentProperty[]),**

So can you please suggest how to go with it.